# About the uniform convergence of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Let $(a_n(z))$ is a sequence of holomorphic functions defined on $\mathbb{C}\setminus A$,  where $A$ is a set of simple poles. I am thinking about proving that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left | a_n(z) \right |$ is uniformly convergent on every compact subset of $\mathbb{C}\setminus A$.

If you have proven that $\left | a_n(z) \right |\leq M_n$, independent of $z$, for all $n\geq N$ (for suitable $N$) on a disc, and that $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}M_n<\infty$, would that answer the question about the uniform convergence? What about $\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\left | a_n(z) \right |$?

Comment: if $|c_n | < M_n$ and $\sum_n M_n$ converges then $\sum_n c_n$ converges yes. and what question ? are $a_n(z)$ uniformly continuous (or better : analytic) on the disk where $|a_n(z)| < M_n$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 I edited the post. Let us say that the sum is written as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left | a_n(z) \right |=\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\left | a_n(z) \right |+\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\left | a_n(z) \right |$. That's why I am wondering if it answers the question about the uniform convergence without mentioning about  $\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\left | a_n(z) \right |$. Maybe I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: and yes sorry I was thinking to uniform continuity. yes of course it is uniformly convergent on $D$, since $|\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n(z)| < \epsilon$ independently of $z \in D$ for $N$ large enough

Comment: @user1952009 OK, so there is no need to worry about $\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\left | a_n(z) \right |$ as long as we found a majorant seres for suitable large $N$?

Comment: let $f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(z)$ and $f_N(z) = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n(z)$ then $f_N(z) \to f(z)$ uniformly on $D$

Comment: the proof being : for any $\epsilon > 0$, find the $N$ such that $\sum_{n > N} M_n < \epsilon$, then $|f_n(z)-f(z)| < \epsilon$ for every $z \in D$